# Leaving Schengen and re-entering different state in less than three months

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I have plans to go to Spain in September (let's say 1st September) and stay only 26 days. But I might have to go to Paris (for three months).

If I go to Paris, let's say 1st May and leave 30th July, will I be able to go in September to Spain, since there's only August in between?

Or if I only spend one month in France (till 1st June) could I continue with my visit to Spain?

If none of this works, could I go let's say next month to Paris (March/April/May) and be back in my state for (June/July/August) and go again to a Schengen state - this time Spain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding the rule. You are allowed to be inside the Schengen area 90 out of 180 days on a rolling basis. In other words, at any given time, you can only spend 90 out of the last 180 days inside the Schengen area. It's entirely up to you whether you want to use your days all at once or enter or exit several times, but every single day that you spend even one minute inside the area counts as one of your days.

You may use [the calculator provided by the European Union](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en) to work out exactly what this means given any arbitrary set of dates.

Note that if your nationality requires a visa to visit the Schengen area, the terms of your visa may be more restrictive in terms of the number of entries and days allowed. If this applies to you, please let us know what your visa says (best yet, post a picture of it with your personal information redacted).

Comment: It would perhaps be better to say "but every single day when you spend any time at all inside the area counts as one of your days", since even arriving at 2359 and departing at 0001 the following day would count as two days under Schengen rules. "every single day you are inside" could be misunderstood as meaning "every day that you spend 24hrs inside".